Custom UObjects are disappearing from TArray declared in GameMode constructor
Topic of how not to have your UObjects garbage collected was revisited on hundreds of posts, but no solution that I found seemed to work for my case.
Here is the MVP project repository: https://github.com/eSqadron/ObjectDisappearingFromTArrayMVP
I have some custom UMyObject : UObject and array of those objects TArray<class UMyObject*> MyObjects; inside of my Game Mode: AMvpGameModeBase. Array is created in the Game Mode constructor. Array is referenced by AMvpGameModeBase::GetNextObject() and AMvpPlayerController::BeginPlay(). Begin Play creates widgets, that are integral part of UMyObject class (Although it would probably also crash the same way without it).
Now, my MVP project shows button, every odd click takes next UMyObject from TArray and shows relevant widget on screen. Every even click hides existing widget. If everything worked as I intended, after 10 screens we should get an error because we run out of array elements. And if we click button fast enough, it is exactly what happens. If we hovewer take a little bit more time (around a minute or so) to give GC time to run, everything suddenly becomes null. Object Names are disappearing, (Null instead of My_Object_XX) can't set widgets text because access violation, etc.
Here you can see that UMyObject Got clearly garbage collecetd:

I've already tried some solutions, but neither seemed to work:
Solution 1:
Set TArray<class UMyObject*> MyObjects; as UPROPERTY(). In this case MyObjects array is filled in Game Mode constructor, but when I reference this array in PlayerController BeginPlay everything is null:

Why is that happening? Is Unreal Reflection System doing something wierd when objects are created in constructor instead of Begin Play?
Solution 2:
Add MyObjects to root, via _newObject->AddToRoot(); in Game Mode constructor. This was partial fix, as objects itselves seem to be not garbage collected anymore, but widgets, that are part of the objects (only MyWidget in the case of this MVP), still are.
Adding MyWidget to root (obj->MyWidget->AddToRoot();) to fix that, was complete disaster. Leaving game without removing all widgets from root was causing crash upon clicking stop button in editor. Also, I was able to run game only in debug mode, clicking play in editor without debug mode from VS caused crash. But the second issue I only observed in my actual poject not this MVP app.
Solution 3:
Create all objects separately with UPROPERTY() and then add them to the TArray MyObjects.
There was no observable difference between this and base behaviour, objects were still disappearing.
Solution 4:
Instead of AddToRoot() set only the flag as RF_MarkAsRootSet.
There was also no observable difference between this and base behaviour, objects were still disappearing.
I also tried some random combinations of these solutions. I feel like first solution would be the most appropriate and "clean", but I have no idea where these nulls come from. I also have a lot to learn about UE Reflection System and their Garbage Collector. I'd greatly appreciate any help as I am sitting on this issue for over a week now.

I think I figured it out, combination of solution 1 and 2:

_newObject->AddToRoot(); is added to root in the Game Mode
Added UPROPERTY() to class UMyWidget* MyWidget;

But it was trial and error, I have no idea why it works, if someone knows how it exactly works and why this solution works, while others are causing issues I'd love to hear some detailed explanation.
